# How can we convert an external table to managed table in SPARK 2.2.0?

Tags: apache-spark

The below command was successfully converting external tables to managed tables in `Spark 2.0.0`:

```
ALTER TABLE {table_name} SET TBLPROPERTIES(EXTERNAL=FLASE);
```

However the above command is failing in `Spark 2.2.0` with the below error:

> Error in query: Cannot set or change the preserved property key:
>   'EXTERNAL';

Comment: Hey @oushnik-dey were you able to find a solution for this? I am trying to accomplish the same.

Comment: I'm on Spark 2.1.0 btw.

Comment: I was able to do it using Pyspark.. please see below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520227/how-to-delete-a-particular-month-from-a-parquet-file-partitioned-by-month/57615684#57615684

Answer (score 6):

As @AndyBrown pointed our in a comment you have the option of dropping to the console and invoking the Hive statement there. In Scala this worked for me:

```
import sys.process._
val exitCode = Seq("hive", "-e", "ALTER TABLE {table_name} SET TBLPROPERTIES(\"EXTERNAL\"=\"FALSE\")").!
```

I faced this problem using Spark 2.1.1 where @Joha's answer does not work because spark.sessionState is not accessible due to being declared lazy.

Answer (score 5):

In Spark 2.2.0 you can do the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.TableIdentifier
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.CatalogTable
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.CatalogTableType

val identifier = TableIdentifier("table", Some("database"))
val oldTable = spark.sessionState.catalog.getTableMetadata(identifier)
val newTableType = CatalogTableType.MANAGED 

val alteredTable = oldTable.copy(tableType = newTableType)

spark.sessionState.catalog.alterTable(alteredTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is case-sensitivity on spark-2.1 and above.

Please try setting TBLPROPERTIES in lower case -

```
    ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME> SET TBLPROPERTIES('external'='false')
```

Comment: Although you have corrected the quoting and spelling of false, putting it in lower case just adds a user property "external" set to "false" and leaves the preserved property "EXTERNAL" as "TRUE" (and retains the table's external state).  You can see this by running "DESCRIBE FORMATTED <tablename>".  I have the same problem as the OP and cannot fix it (I will post and answer if I find one), but this is not the answer.

Comment: @AndyBrown  did you find how to resolve set external = false . I am getting error as you described org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot set or change the preserved property key: 'EXTERNAL';

Comment: @donald sort of.  I found a workaround that was so specific to my use-case I didn't consider it a suitable answer to this question:  Because I'm operating in pyspark, I dropped to the shell and called the hive engine directly to execute the SET command, which worked because the error only occurred in spark context.  Happy to expound in chat if you think this might be useful.

Comment: Hey @AndyBrown could you please elaborate on how you've worked around this issue? Please post your answer/code as I'm encountering the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using a hive external table. I solved the problem by directly setting the propery external to false in hive metastore using a hive metastore client

```
 Table table = hiveMetaStoreClient.getTable("db", "table");
 table.putToParameters("EXTERNAL","FALSE");
 hiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table("db", "table", table,true);
```

Comment: Could you further elaborate how you access the hiveMetaStoreClient from Spark 2? As far as I can see you need a HiveConf for this which is no longer available.

Comment: Table object doesn't have method `putToParameters` as of spark 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above option from scala databricks notebook, and the
 external table was converted to MANAGED table and the good part is
 that the desc formatted option from spark on the new table is still
 showing the location to be on my ADLS. This was one limitation that
 spark was having, that we cannot specify the location for a managed
 table.

As of now i am able to do a truncate table for this. hopefully there
 was a more direct option for creating a managed table with location
 specified from spark sql.